# Count Preg Split Rows?

Tags: php, preg-split

Is it possible to count the amount of items prepared from the preg_split function?

Example:

Lets Say `$_REQUEST['p']` = Index/Home

`$str = preg_split('(/)', $_REQUEST['p']);`

So:

`$str[0] = Index`
`$str[1] = Home`

Is it even possible to count these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use `explode` instead `preg_split` to this simple split procedure.

```
$tokens = explode('/', $_REQUEST['p']);
echo count($tokens); // counting tokens
```

It is much less computational demanding.

Answer (score 1):

[`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) will return an array, so a simple [`count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) would do.

```
$str = preg_split('(/)', $_REQUEST['p']);

echo 'There are ' . count($str) . ' occurrences';
```

Alternative, there is also [`substr_count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) to count the number of occurrences in a string.